# Determining the optimum number of worker threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, java.util.concurrent

Imagine, that we have X (30 for example) number of system. Each system has an 
array of Entities on which it has to operate (the number of Entities for a system is different for each) . So basically, systems contain algorithms and Entities contain data to be acted upon. Each system can specify what kind of Entities it can act upon, thus an Entity can be operated upon by multiple systems.

The systems are arranged in a chain, meaning that we run then sequentially, not in paralell. They are called upon in the same sequence each time to act upon their Entities (all we have to do is call their System::process method.

This system chain is run 60 times each second.

---

Currently, it is implemented so that a system runs on a single thred, processing it's Entities sequentially. I'd like to have concurrency.

Systems do not have state, therefore we can safely call their process methods on multiple threads at once, given that we tell each method call on which portion of the system's Entities should it work on.

Example: we determin that we have 2 cores available, therefore we run each system on 2 threads. One of the threads calls a system's process method and tells it to process from 0 to 20 (indexes of the array containing the Entities), the other thread calls the same system's process method and tells it to process from 20 to 40.

---

Now the questions: what is the optimal number of threads the load should be distributed on, taking the probable cache size and cores and what not into account. (Maybe decided empirically by testing?)

What would be the most efficent way to manage the Threads (thread pool etc.)?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding something, but it sounds like a job for `ForkJoinPool`.

Comment: But a simple executor service could be adequate too, if you don't need to synchronize between the tasks. Just throw in all the jobs and the scheduler should do the rest.

Comment: Take a look at "The Art of Concurrency" by Clay Breshears. It is a really good book concerning the implementation of concurrent algorithms, transforming serial algorithms into concurrent algorithms, and when/if you should do so.